# How can I get average of groupings in a table and store the result back to the original table in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
| Country | Month | Revenue |
|---------|-------|---------|
| US      | Jan   | 100     |
| US      | Feb   | 200     |
| US      | Mar   | 300     |
| Canada  | Jan   | 200     |
| Canada  | Feb   | 400     |
| Canada  | Mar   | 500     |
```

I need to get average revenue per country and store this value back to the original table to get the following output:

```
| Country | Month | Revenue | Average |
|---------|-------|---------|---------|
| US      | Jan   | 100     | 200     |
| US      | Feb   | 200     | 200     |
| US      | Mar   | 300     | 200     |
| Canada  | Jan   | 200     | 366.6   |
| Canada  | Feb   | 400     | 366.6   |
| Canada  | Mar   | 500     | 366.6   |
```

What is the best way to accomplish this in SQL? Is it better to use partition by?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I'm using T-SQL

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this uses window functions:

```
select t.*, avg(revenue) over (partition by country) as avg_revenue
from t;
```

To actually do the computation and store it back requires an `update`.  Although there are other methods, the following is standard SQL:

```
update t
    set average = (select avg(revenue) from t t2 where t.country = t2.country);
```

EDIT:

In T-SQL, you can somewhat improve the performance by doing:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             avg(t.revenue) over (partition by t.country) as new_average
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set average = new_average;
```